# .htaccess redirect old domain to new domain but exclude non-www version, robots.txt and one file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect old domain to new domain but leave **non-www homepage**, **robots.txt** and one single file (**myfile.html**) behind.
Here is what i am trying to do

```
all www.olddomain.com > all www.newdomain.com
olddomain.com > 404 error
olddomain.com/robots.txt > olddomain.com/robots.txt
olddomain.com/myfile.html > olddomain.com/myfile.html
```

Here is what i have tried below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(myfile\.html|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://olddomanin.com [R=410,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For some reason it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code at root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(myfile\.html|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=404,L]

# above code will capture any request not having www except myfile.html &
# robots.txt and directed to 404 error page and if you want 410 change it 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(myfile\.html|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# the above code will capture every request that passed the above rule 
# except myfile.html & robots.txt and redirected it to a new domain
```